DocuSign ListStatusChangeOptions : The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Invalid value for query string parameter 'from_date'
When we pass the form_date to the listStatusChangesoptions and call the ListStatusChanges API to get the envelope details, it always returns null values. How can we handle this issue?
I have already searched the internet but I can't find anything, can anyone help me.

Please make sure you include both form_date and to_date in your request.
Here is more information on searching for envelopes, just in case:
Searching for envelopes
We hope this helps.
Regards
Adrian
DS
